# How to pass function parameters in Vue to make a GET request using axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to send a GET request with Vue instead of sending it with POSTMAN for my small learning project. I have this code that handels that:

```
<tr v-for="(cabinet, i) in cabinets">
    <td>{{ cabinet }}</td>
</tr>
<script>
const axios = require('axios');

export default {
    name: "Cabinets",
    data() {
      return {
          cabinets: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
        getCabinets($id) {
            axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'user/{id}/cabinets'
            })
                .then(response => {
                    this.cabinets = response.data
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

For some reason I'm unable to see how this should work excatly even after seeing many related questions. In POSTMAN I would do `http://my.domain:PORT_NUMBER/user/815/cabinets`. How would I be able to pass the id 815 and test it/show the results in Vue? When running this in Postman I get a JSON response that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "idOfCabinet": 666,
        "belongToUser": 815,
        "time": "2018-06-18 11:51:22",
        "toucher": "person1",
    },
    {
        "idOfCabinet": 23,
        "belongToUser": 815,
        "time": "2019-09-11 10:51:22",
        "toucher": "person3",
    }

]
```

Comment: where do you use your `getCabinets` method?

Comment: Use backticks (\`): url:\`user/${$id}/cabinets\`

Comment: @Jérôme That's the thing, I don't. I'm unable to see how to call it on the same page to view its results

Comment: @Doesitmatter Do you have the id you when to pass somewhere in your Vue app? Maybe in the route or store?

Comment: yes I do, it's the `id` of the account that's currently logged in. I can obtain that easily but just for testing purposes, I'm hard-coding an `id` now to see how this stuff work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mounted()` function of the Vue instance, it will be triggered as soon as the component is mounted

cf: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

for example:

```js
<tr v-for="(cabinet, i) in cabinets">
    <td>{{ cabinet }}</td>
</tr>
<script>
const axios = require('axios');

export default {
  name: "Cabinets",
  data() {
    return {
      cabinets: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      // Use backticks to do string interpolation
      // Replace the id variable by the correct id definition (idk where you get it)
      url: `user/${this.$session.get('user').id}/cabinets`
    }).then(response => {
      this.cabinets = response.data
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You mentioned in the comments calling the actual function, I don't see a function call here. Is this how it's supposed to work?

Comment: The call is automatically done when your component is being mounted, it's a part of the VueJS lifecycle. With the mounted function you don't have to call it somewhere in your component/template. You can learn more about that here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: The way you did is more appropriated for functions used by buttons for example, or when you need another action to be completed (like user interactions)

Comment: Don't use parameters with the mounted function, use it like you do (data value) or directly use `this.$session.get('user')` inside the axios url interpolation. I edited my answer

Comment: Then data value usage seems to me the best option

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response using `axios`.

```
    axios.get('user/${$id}/cabinets')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.cabinets = response.data
    })
```